# How can I take user input using a post-receive hook in GitLab?

Tags: linux, bash, gitlab

I have an auto-deployment script using a post-receive hook in GitLab. Now, I am trying to make it more functional as it only triggered the auto-deploy script. What I want is that it can take input from the developer like entering the project name etc. I have tried this functionality, but it didn't work.

Comment: Duplicate to [git-post-receive-user-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243020/git-post-receive-user-input)

Comment: confused. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: did you try using `exec < /dev/tty` ? is not working for you ?

Comment: no i haven't tried it yet